# TableView to DetailView Video - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, detailview

I'm finding any tutorial to push tableview to detailview but I didn't find any good tutorial. All i want is that when I click on any cell it will open a URL video for example http://www.faafafasf.com/play-vlc-video-001

Can someone help me with it?
I'll really appreciate it. Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you will have to combine a couple of tutorials.   assume you found something that will make a table and then when you select a cell will take you to a detail view.  For your detail ViewController implement the following tutorial to call a URL, including a video:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift